# Not able to compile UserInfo.UITheme() or UserInfo.UIThemeDisplayed()

Tags: lightning

Compiler says there is no such method in System.UserInfo class. Any idea how I can get this value in Apex?

SF Docs says: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2016/04/introducing-ui-theme-detection-for-lightning-experience.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A paragraph in that blog post is not consistent with the [actual API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) in use today. The example further down the page is.

The method names are:

```
UserInfo.getUiTheme()
UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed()
```

You can use the "[+] Feedback" button on the right edge of the page to report the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the metadata version of your apex class make sure it's the latest, alternatively if it's not available you can send it as a parameter in the remote action